# Explicitly add Swift to an Objective-C Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have an Objective-C application where I wanted to move some functionality into a framework. I decided to write that framework in Swift (which was a blast). However, when I tried to consume the Swift framework, I got runtime dynamic link error:

```
`dyld`__abort_with_payload
```

It appeared that my application wasn't including and linking a necessary part of the Swift toolchain.

The only way I was able to get Xcode to include Swift in my project was to add a dummy Swift file. Xcode noticed the Swift file and added the necessary configuration to my application. After that everything worked fine, even after deleting the file.

**My question is, is there a more elegant way to consume a Swift framework from an Objective-C project, or add Swift to a project without Swift source files?**

Thanks for the help!

(I'm using Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3, MacOS 10.12.6)

Comment: What's more elegant than simply adding a Swift file to the project? Your other options are probably involve finding all the relevant project settings and changing them manually.

Comment: I'd prefer to give someone else a script that changes the relevant project settings then tell them to add, and then delete, an empty swift file. It's confusing.

Comment: Before Swift reaches ABI stability the dylibs for runtime are included on application level to keep exact version. Include the files manually and also inspect the binary if it contains all the necessary load commands for the "no swift scenario". You can use `otool` or `MachOView` for that. As an added bonus you do have a binary that works so use that as your reference.

Comment: @Kamil.S do you mean manually move the files that currently exist in the framework into the application?

Comment: If needed yes. Compare the file structure of non-Swift and Swift including project, at least the latter one should contain the Swift runtime dylibs lying next to the main executable in the same directory.

Comment: I'm confused because I can see the swift libraries included in my framework. But there's still dylib runtime errors unless the same libraries are in the application.